# C++ Aborted core dumped at the end of its execution

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector

I am fairly new to C++ and am currently doing a school assignment on vectors. The header file contains the implementation of the functions required to meet the requirements. I am about done with the program but unfortunately, at the end of its execution, it gave an 'aborted core dumped' message. I can't seem to figure out why that is. Everything worked perfectly well till it reaches the end. It is during the assign test that it gives out that message. I would need your expertise on this. Thank you!

My Output:

```
********** TestAssign **********
push_back 10 floats:
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 (size=10 capacity=16)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (size=10 capacity=16)
Assign: b = a, print a,b
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 (size=10 capacity=16)
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 (size=10 capacity=16)
Assign: a = a, print a
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 (size=10 capacity=16)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

School's Output(Correct one):

```
********** TestAssign **********
push_back 10 floats:
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 (size=10 capacity=16)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (size=10 capacity=16)
Assign: b = a, print a,b
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 (size=10 capacity=16)
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 (size=10 capacity=16)
Assign: a = a, print a
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 (size=10 capacity=16)
```

Header file(My Implementation):

```
template <typename T>
vec 
{

private:
T* v;
int count;
int capacity;
public:

vector(){ //default constructor
    capacity=0;
    v = nullptr;
    count = 0;
}

vector(const vector& b) //copy contructor
{
count = b.count;
capacity = b.capacity;
v = new T[capacity];
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
{
    this->v[i] = b.v[i];
}
}   

 vector(vector&& tmp): v(tmp.v),//move constructor
                      count(tmp.count),
                      capacity(tmp.capacity)
{
    tmp.v = nullptr;
}

~vector() {//destructor

if (v != NULL);
    {
        delete [] v;
        v = NULL;
    }
}

void push_back(const T& t)
{
    if(count+1>capacity)
{
    capacity = std::max(2*capacity, 1);

    T* newData = new T[capacity];
    for(int i=0; i <count; i++)
    {
        newData[i] = v[i];
    }
    delete[] v;
    v = newData;
}
v[count++] = t;
}

T pop_back() {
    //..
}

size_t size() const
    {
        //..
    }

bool empty() 
{ 
  //..
}   

 T operator[](unsigned index) const //subscript operator
 {
     //...
 }

 T& operator[](unsigned index) //subscript operator 
 { 
    //...
 }

void clear(){
    //...
}

void erase(T position)
{
  //...
}

void insert(int index, T number)
{
    //...
}

vector& operator = (const vector &rhs) //copy assignment
{
    ../
}

vector& operator=(vector&& rhs) { //move assignment

    if (this != &rhs) {
        delete[] v;
        this->v = rhs.v;
        rhs.v = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename T1>
friend void Print(const vector<T1>& s); //friend print

friend  void Print(const vector<unsigned char>& s);     //friend print if 
//unsigned

};
template <typename T1>
void Print(const vector<T1>& s)
{
    // std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    for(int i = 0; i < s.count; i++) 
    {
    std::cout<<s.v[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<< "(size=" << s.count << " " << "capacity=" << s.capacity << 
")";
    std::cout<<std::endl; 
    }

void Print(const vector<unsigned char>& s)
{
    //...
}
```

Main file:

```
void TestAssign(void)
{
std::cout << "\n********** TestAssign **********\n";
cs150::vector<float> a, b;

std::cout << "push_back 10 floats:\n";
for (float i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a.push_back(2 * i);
    b.push_back(i);
}

Print(a);
Print(b);

std::cout << "Assign: b = a, print a,b\n";
b = a;
Print(a);
Print(b);

std::cout << "Assign: a = a, print a\n";
a = a;
Print(a);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially how to use a debugger to catch crashes "in action" to locate when and where in your code it happens.

Comment: There are also some other points about your code that might be worth mentioning: For example that your copy-constructor copies `capacity` number of elements, instead of `count` number of elements. This actually leads to *undefined behavior* since if `count < capacity` then you will copy *uninitialized* data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your assignment operator:

```
vector& operator = (const vector &rhs) //copy assignment
{
    v = rhs.v;
    return *this;
}
```

That copies the pointer `v` instead of making a copy of the underlying array (you also forget to copy the other members, `count` and `capacity`)

As a result, after `b = a;` you end up double-freeing the same array in `a` and `b`, which leads to a segfault.

Change the assignment operator to be more like the copy constructor:

```
vector& operator = (const vector &b) //copy assignment
{
    if (this != &b) {
        count = b.count;
        capacity = b.capacity;
        v = new T[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            this->v[i] = b.v[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

---

Unrelated note: you have an extra `;` in the destructor:

```
    if (v != NULL);
                  ^ here
```

I would also leave move semantics out of it for now, unless you're required to support it.

Comment: Hi @rustyx, thanks for the advice. However, I now get this as output: 0 2.8026e-45 5.60519e-45 8.40779e-45 1.12104e-44 1.4013e-44 1.68156e-44 1.96182e-44 2.24208e-44 2.52234e-44 (size=10 capacity=16)

Comment: I followed your code as mentioned above and got the above output.

Comment: Yes, that's because `a = a;` makes no sense. If you want to support that as a no-op, the assignment operator needs to recognize that situation and not attempt to copy anything. For example wrap it in `if (this != &rhs) { }`

Comment: Aight, all is well now. Thanks a whole lot guys!